# How to select a cell in Spyder 3.10 IPython Console

Tags: ipython, spyder

I'm new to Spyder IDE and I'm using Spyder 3.10 on Windows. Looking for a way to edit a previous cell in the IPython console.  Using the Jupyter, I liked being able to up/down arrow to move from cell to cell.  Can I do something similar in Spyder?

I understand that using up/down arrow in Spyder's IPython console auto completes a previous cell (using a new line number), but sometimes I want to edit a cell directly.  I also looked at the keyboard shortcuts and didn't see this functionality.

Thank you for your help.